# PyArray_SimpleNewFromData

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, numpy

So I am trying to write a C function that accepts a numpy array object, extracts the data, does some manipulations and returns another c array as a numpy array object. Everything works seamlessly and I use python wrappers which help easy manipulation on the python side. However, I am facing a memory leak. I have an output pointer of doubles that I malloc-ed and which I wrap into a Python array object just before returning it to the calling python function,

```
PyObject *arr;
int nd = 2;
npy_intp dims[] = {5, 10};
double *data = some_function_that_returns_a_double_star(x, y, z);

arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void *)data);
return arr;
```

However, this creates a memory leak, because data is never freed and I did some googling to find that this is a problem in such applications and solution is non-trivial. The most helpful resource that I found on this is [given here](http://blog.enthought.com/python/numpy-arrays-with-pre-allocated-memory/#.W71cEWhKhEY). I could not implement the destructor that this page talks about from the given example. Can someone help me with this? More concretely I am looking for something like,

```
PyObject *arr;
int nd = 2;
npy_intp dims[] = {5, 10};
double *data = some_function_that_returns_a_double_star(x, y, z);

arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void *)data);
some_destructor_that_plug_memLeak_due_to_data_star(args);
return arr;
```

> - [Numpy Array C APIs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/c-api.array.html)
> - [Numpy C APIs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The technique described in the link you didn't understand is a good one: create a Python object that knows how to free your memory when destroyed, and make it the base of the returned array.

It sounds like you might have been overwhelmed by the complexity of creating a new extension type. Fortunately, that's not necessary. Python comes with a type designed to perform arbitrary C-level cleanup when destroyed: [capsules](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/capsule.html), which bundle together a pointer and a destructor function and call the destructor when the capsule is destroyed.

To create a capsule for your memory, first, we define a destructor function:

```
void capsule_cleanup(PyObject *capsule) {
    void *memory = PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, NULL);
    // I'm going to assume your memory needs to be freed with free().
    // If it needs different cleanup, perform whatever that cleanup is
    // instead of calling free().
    free(memory);
}
```

And you set a capsule as your array's base with

```
PyObject *capsule = PyCapsule_New(data, NULL, capsule_cleanup);
PyArray_SetBaseObject((PyArrayObject *) arr, capsule);
// Do not Py_DECREF the capsule; PyArray_SetBaseObject stole your
// reference.
```

And that should ensure your memory gets freed once it's no longer in use.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ... that was really neat ... seems to have actually plugged my leak ... couldn't find this anywhere when I was searching for a fix. Very elegant. Just a couple of pointers though,

(a) `void *memory = PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, NULL);`
(b) when I compile the above code, I get the following warning - 

`passing argument 1 of ‘(int (*)(PyArrayObject *, PyObject *))*(PyArray_API + 2256u)’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Any ideas on averting this?

Comment: @ArnabSanyal: Thanks for pointing out the missing argument; I'd forgotten capsule names were used for that. As for the pointer type warning, there was a missing cast.

Comment: You're welcome @user2357112. This was a real lifesaver though. Tested it. works like a charm !!

Comment: I found this in caffe library, maybe someone will help: "boost python expects a void (missing) return value, while import_array" "returns NULL for python3. import_array1() forces a void return value."

Comment: To avoid memory corruption, extension writers should never try to operate on Python objects with the functions exported by the C library: malloc(), calloc(), realloc() and free(). This is mentioned in https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html. i dout this is not a good approach, tho.

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner: We're not calling `free` on a Python object, though. We're calling `free` on a buffer allocated by the questioner's C code, not by the Python memory management system. It needs to be freed in whatever way is appropriate for how the questioner's C code allocated it.

Comment: @user2357112 Also, I wonder how can we check that the capsule_cleanup is called? I put a printf(or even tried to create a dummy file) inside of it and nothing printed

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner: Then it probably wasn't called. A `printf` inside `capsule_cleanup` will go to C stdout as normal. (This might sometimes be different from `sys.stdout`, since reassigning `sys.stdout` doesn't affect the C-level standard streams.) Maybe you have a reference count bug?

Comment: @user2357112 You're right. Py_finalize() seems to work incorrectly. I've tested the same code in Python script itself and it works!

Answer (score 7):

While the `PyCapsule` approach works more generally, you can get numpy to free the memory in the array for you when it's garbage collected by setting the `OWNDATA` flag.

```
double *data = some_function_that_returns_a_double_star(x, y, z);
PyObject *arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void *)data);
PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS((PyArrayObject*) arr, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
```