# Crash of Jupyter due to the use of PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS

Tags: python, c, numpy, jupyter-notebook, cython

I try to convert a C double* in numpy array on Cython but I didn't succeed yet.
I found these usefull links:
[Force NumPy ndarray to take ownership of its memory in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872946/force-numpy-ndarray-to-take-ownership-of-its-memory-in-cython)
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8253

But everytime I use the following .pyx file with Cython it makes Jupyter crash (dead kernel):

.c file:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

double* test1(int n) {
  double* A=(double*)calloc(n,sizeof(double));
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    A[i]=i+0.5; }
  return(A); }
```

I also try with malloc with the same result.

.pyx file:

```
cimport c_test
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h":
    void PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(np.ndarray arr, int flags)

cdef data_to_numpy_array_with_spec(void * ptr, np.npy_intp N, int t):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &N, t, ptr)
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(arr, np.NPY_OWNDATA)
    return arr

def test(n):
    cdef double* t1
    t=data_to_numpy_array_with_spec(c_test.test1(n),n,np.NPY_FLOAT64)
    return(t)
```

The c_fct.test1 function return a C double* of n double that I want to convert into a numpy array which own the data to avoid memory leak. Without the line `PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(t, np.NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA)` everything works fine but the memory is not deallocated when the numpy array is destroyed.

jupyter notebook:

```
import cy_test as ct
ct.test(1000)
```

c_test.pxd file:

```
cdef extern from "test.h":
    double* test1(int n)
```

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("cy_test", ["cy_test.pyx","test.c"])])


setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
  include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
)
```

I think that my problem may come from the same reason as in the github link but I don't see how to solve it (in my case the C pointer already exist so I think I can't use the same solution).

I work on Windows 10 with Anaconda 64bits, here are the detail of the version:
3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: I think we might need to see code for c_test.test too

Comment: I add the .pxd file, is that what you wanted?

Comment: I'm more interested in the test.c file it uses. It's possible that it's a more complicated problem, but it's worth being sure there's nothing simple in the code that allocates the memory.

Comment: The other information that might be useful is information about your system - Windows/Linux? What compiler? The GitHub link implies that this might be a compiler mismatch on Windows - if so I don't think I know how to fix it, but it'll need that information for anyone to help.

Comment: Right, I work on Windows 10, with Anaconda 64 bits (details: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8253) that you linked, `NPY_OWNDATA` is only safe to use with memory allocated through the same allocator NumPy itself uses. This allocator can be accessed through the [`PyDataMem_*`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/c-api.array.html#memory-management) functions. If your memory does not come from this allocator, you cannot use `NPY_OWNDATA`.

Don't try to force an array to take ownership of arbitrary memory you give it. Instead, set the array's *base* to an object that knows how to perform the correct cleanup, using [`PyArray_SetBaseObject`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SetBaseObject). A [capsule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731884/pyarray-simplenewfromdata/52732077#52732077) may be a convenient object to use.

Comment: One good option for memory ownership might be [a Cython array, which can have a callback set for destruction](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays). These are readily converted to a numpy array by `np.asarray(cython_array_variable)`.(since they have the Python buffer interface)

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to you it's done, all I had to do was to modified the .pyx file like this:

```
cimport c_test
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.stdlib cimport free

np.import_array()

ctypedef void (*PyCapsule_Destructor)(void*)

cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h":
    void* PyCapsule_GetPointer(void* capsule, const char *name)
    void* PyCapsule_New(void *pointer, const char *name, PyCapsule_Destructor destructor)
    int PyArray_SetBaseObject(np.ndarray arr, void* obj)


cdef void capsule_cleanup(void* capsule):
    cdef void *memory = PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, NULL)
    free(memory)

def test(n):
  cdef np.ndarray arr
  cdef int nd = 1
  cdef np.npy_intp shape[1]
  shape[0] = <np.npy_intp> n
  cdef double *data = c_test.test1(n)
  arr = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, shape, np.NPY_DOUBLE, data)
  cdef void* capsule = PyCapsule_New(data, NULL, capsule_cleanup)
  PyArray_SetBaseObject( arr, capsule)
  return(arr)
```